# How should I solve SEO problem for my blog?

Tags: react

I am a blogger, I have my website on WordPress, but as a developer, I want to build my own blog with the skills I have.

I am looking to build a website like Medium.com or Scotch.io. So for such a blog/website, do I need to use SSR or Static file generation specifically ? Because obviously I will need SEO and a little boost in performance but I am hesitant with complexity of SSR when it comes to NodeJS/Express.

What should I do:

- Go with Gatsby ? (I still don't understand why we should use it ? )
- Go with SSR tutorials from medium using Express and confuse myself even more?
- Go with the basic Create React App that I am already using ? I already run it with express on same port with Proxy and serve the index.html , Google seems to read it fine.
- Go with Razzle and Be happy with what it offers?
- Go with EJS/Pug and do JQuery (I hate JQuery and I don't get it)?
- Use Next JS and be stuck with no React Router Support?

What I am currently doing :

Express server with mongoose for mongoDB , serves the create-react-app's index.html , and that's about it.

What I know :

Basics Of React,Angular, VueJS, HTML, CSS, JQuery, Node + Express, Mongoose, Next JS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the most important thing is site audit and it should have a clear goal. That is, we must ask ourselves why we are doing it. And here metrics of work efficiency come to the rescue.

I selected them in 4 groups:

• SEO.

• Usability.

• Business.

• Technical.